# javascript to calculate cost then display in html page

Tags: javascript, html

Just learning javascript and would appreciate assistance to achieve the following:

The visitor can choose options from three drop down boxes (size, color, quantity), then press submit.  Javascript will calculate the value of each and display the result as a value in a div of the HTML page.

EG,

- small=$10, medium=$20, large=$30
- black=$3, red=$5, blue=$7
- amount multiplies the above based on qty

How would I achieve this? with the script and change the HTML output result?

Many thanks!

Comment: Without writing your code for you, you can assign the dollar cost of each item in the select's value and then once all selections are made, add the values and assign the resulting sum to the innerHTML of the div you have chosen.

Comment: @todd.pund - So frustrating when you try to retain the intended spirit of the site and answer a basic question with helpful pointers and someone else swings in looking for low-hanging rep with their JSfiddle to provide working code to cut and paste ensuring that nobody learns anything valuable. Very disappointing. You got my upvote, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kRTv5/3/) should get you started:

```
<div>
    Size
    <select id="size">
        <option value="10">Small</option>
        <option value="20">Medium</option>
        <option value="30">Large</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    Color
    <select id="color">
        <option value="3">Black</option>
        <option value="5">Red</option>
        <option value="7">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    Quantity
    <input id="quantity" type="text" placeholder="Quantity" />
</div>
<div>
    Total cost: <span id="total"></span>
</div>
```

and

```
$('#size').change(function(){
    var size = parseInt($(this).val()),
        color = parseInt($('#color').val()),
        quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val()),
        total = (size + color) * quantity;
    $('#total').html(total);
});

$('#color').change(function(){
    var size = parseInt($('#size').val()),
        color = parseInt($(this).val()),
        quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val()),
        total = (size + color) * quantity;
    $('#total').html(total);
});

$('#quantity').change(function(){
    var size = parseInt($('#size').val()),
        color = parseInt($('#color').val()),
        quantity = parseInt($(this).val()),
        total = (size + color) * quantity;
    $('#total').html(total);
});
```

Comment: This is jQuery, OP asked for javaScript.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var qty=1;

function sanitize() {
  var o=document.getElementById('qty');
  if (!o) return;
  var newqty=parseInt(o.value);
  if (isNaN(newqty)) o.value=qty;
  else {
    qty=newqty;
    update();
  }
}

function update() {
  var total=0;
  var o=document.getElementById('size');
  if (!o) return;
  var tmp=parseInt(o.options[o.selectedIndex].value);
  if (isNaN(tmp)) return;
  total=tmp;
  o=document.getElementById('color');
  if (!o) return;
  var tmp=parseInt(o.options[o.selectedIndex].value);
  if (isNaN(tmp)) return;
  total*=tmp;
  o=document.getElementById('qty');
  if (!o) return;
  var tmp=parseInt(o.value);
  if (isNaN(tmp)) return;
  total*=tmp;
  o=document.getElementById('total');
  if (!o) return;
  o.innerHTML=tmp.toString();
}


</script>

<form action="javascript:return false;"> <!-- old browsers will freak out on select without form -->
Size: <select id="size" onchange="update();">
  <option value="10">small</option>
  <option value="20">medium</option>
  <option value="30">large</option>
</select><br>
Color: <select id="color" onchange="update();">
  <option value="3">black</option>
  <option value="5">red</option>
  <option value="7">blue</option>
</select><br>
Qty: <input type="text" id="qty" value="1" onchange="sanitize();">
<form>
Total $: <span id="total">0</span>
```

Comment: [This really isn't helpful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184720/answers-with-too-much-code-and-too-little-explanation)

Comment: You really should read that link. This answer is a perfect example of a low quality answer; there's nothing enviable about it. This is a Question and Answer site, not a request and code-dump site. Sure, OP might be able to copy-paste your code and use it but anyone else with a similar problem will learn nothing from this.

Comment: If you think my answer is "a perfect example of a low quality answer" you should simply downvote it - it's as easy as that. Alternativly you could expend your energy by giving a better answer.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to downvote and there was no need to answer because a perfectly legitimate comment was made on the original post which I up-voted. It gave pointers to OP on how to achieve this rather than a load of code which achieves it for them.

Comment: Good! So we are done here! There were 2 people bothering to try and help the OP by writing self-explaining example code, both of them were now duly punished in an attempt to try to retain the intended spirit of the site. Works for me!

Comment: This code simply isn't "self explaining", especially to someone "just learning javascript" as OP claims to be. The down-votes are for being unhelpful. You should spend some time on meta stackoverflow and read the blog of the creator of the stackexchange model. Maybe then you'll understand the intended spirit of the site.

Comment: Thank you again for making clear to me the intended spirit of the site. You might want to refocus your energy onto actually answering some questions. EOD.

Comment: Just trying to keep the quality high.

Comment: appreciate the code example, it gives me an insight how it functions but I cant seem to make it work. When values are changed via the dropdown box, only the qty increases (by one for each qty), the size or color has no effect on the total.